# PHP Array to string conversion with preg_match

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this error while I'm using this my script:

```
$pages = array('/about.php', '/');

//...............function text here................//

$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$mobiles = '/iphone|ipad|android|symbian|BlackBerry|HTC|iPod|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|WinPhone7|Nokia|samsung|LG/i';

if (preg_match($mobiles, $ua)) {
  $thispage = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if ($thispage == $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$pages) {
     ob_start("text");
}
}
```

This script changes certain pages style depending on user's useragent. I need this script in such way. But I don't know how to make it in PHP properly. Maybe I need some "foreach ($pages as $i)"? But it didn't work in a way I made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to check if the "requested resource" `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is in predefined list of resource paths.
Change your condition as shown below(using `in_array` function):

```
...
if (in_array($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $pages)) {
     ob_start("text");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mega much! =)